# Pass a indicator from Bash back to Perl over SSH via STDIN

Tags: linux, bash, perl, unix

We have a Linux server which can run a diagnostic script, `diag.pl`, which coordinates reporting over other servers.

`diag.pl` iterates over the child servers, and for each of them, SSHs in and runs a bash script, which passes information back:

```
my $cmd=sprintf("ssh %s sudo /usr/lib/support/report.sh -e %s | uudecode -o \"%s-outfile.tgz\") 2>%1 |", $server, $specialparam, $servername)
```

The line of code in `report.sh` that sends the data back is:

```
 uuencode --base64 ${REPORT}.tar.gz /dev/stdout
```

I would like to update `report.sh` to send back an additional line of information, something like:

```
 echo "special-file-found=${SFF}" > /tmp/sff.cfg
 uuencode --base64 /tmp/sff.cfg > /dev/stdout
```

Once the special file has been found, the Perl script will update so that it no longer sends the `specialparam` back to subsequent `report.sh` calls.

Is there a good way to send that input so that it will be easy for Perl to catch it?

**What have I tried**

1. Setting a `user.comment` attr on the tar.gz using `setattr`, but the comment does not survive the uuencoding
2. Currently thinking that my best bet is to use the pseudocode above, creating a new file to encode and send along, and update the Perl script to check it with each new transmission until it finds the special file.

Comment: We'll need to see more of the code.

Comment: I'm just asking about how to send the indicator, not anything to do with the rest of the logic (which is substantial). What more would you like to see?

Comment: A main point of [this guide to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) is creating an [example of what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to suggest improvements. Without it folk might be inclined to downvote for [no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), or of course, [no MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). Give us context. :)

Comment: Your perl command invokes the report.sh script and uudecodes the entire output. Now you want the report script to print the uuencoded data **and** some plain text?

Comment: I think it all has to be uuencoded data because of how the network works. I'll update my question.

Comment: I am not sure that I get it ... if you need to change the shell script called by a Perl script so that it sends back yet more information, can you not just add to the shell script a print to `STDOUT`? I don't know how you run the shell script, but you can do it so to get every "line" as it is printed.  Then you can check each line to see whether it conforms to some "protocol" (for instance, whether it is, or starts with, `special-file-found` string) and act accordingly -- set flags for further calls or write control file for following runs, etc. If it doesn't, it's the encoded file.

Comment: zdim That pretty much answers my question, if you want to post it as an Answer and get a nice check mark :) Thanks!

Comment: Alright, posted, with a basic example.  Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that the objective is to modify a shell script which returns to the caller an encoded file, so that it sends yet more information, specifically a string to be used as a flag in the caller.

It is not clear how the shell script is run from the Perl script, but there are ways to do this so that the caller gets back separate "lines" that are printed, either as they are emitted or altogether after the run completes.

Then you can just add to the shell script the needed extra print to `STDOUT`, and in the caller check each line of shell output to see whether it conforms to some "protocol;" for example, whether it is, or starts with, *special-file-found* string. Then you can set flags for further calls or write control file for following runs, etc. Otherwise, the line is the encoded file.

A made-up basic example using [pipe-open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) (see by the end of the page)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @cmd = qw(ls -l ./);

my $file_found = quotemeta 'special-file-found';

my ($flag, $binfile);

my $pid = open(my $out, '-|', @cmd)   // die "Can't open @cmd: $!";

while (<$out>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^$file_found/) { 
        $flag = 1;
    }
    else {
        $binfile = $_;
        # whatever else need be done, or perhaps  last;
    }
}
close $out;
```

This example runs the command `ls -l ./` but instead of it you can run any executable, like `@cmd = ('report.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2',...)`.

Another way is to use *backticks* ([qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)) and assign its return to an array, in which case each element receives a line of output.

Yet another, better, way is to use a module which manages  external commands.  For example, from simple to more capable: [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple), [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny), [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3), [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run).